# How can I do the equivalent of ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS in cockroachdb/postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb

Most PostgreSQL statements support an IF NOT EXISTS clause to allow for idempotent migrations, e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo ...`. But `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` doesn't. How can I write a SQL statement that will add a constraint if it doesn't already exist, and otherwise do nothing and not error?

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of annoying gap in the PostgreSQL syntax. Here are some workarounds:

**For Unique Constraints**

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS indexname ON tablename(columns)
```

This is equivalent to adding a unique constraint, because unique constraints are implemented by adding an index.

**Using PLSQL**

From [here](https://gist.github.com/estysdesu/e64cd53a174ae1864eef099510f5dfc2):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_constraint_if_not_exists (t_name text, c_name text, constraint_sql text)
  RETURNS void
AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    -- Look for our constraint
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT constraint_name
                   FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage
                   WHERE constraint_name = c_name) THEN
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || t_name || ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' || c_name || ' ' || constraint_sql;
    END IF;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT create_constraint_if_not_exists('pokemon', 'league_max', 'CHECK (cp < 1500);');
```

This works in Postgres. PL/pgSQL isn't supported in CockroachDB yet (as of October 2022) but is coming soon.

**In Code**

```rb
if sqlconn.Query("SELECT 1
                   FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage
                   WHERE constraint_name = league_max").empty?
  sqlConn.Exec("ALTER TABLE pokemon ADD CONSTRAINT league_max ...")
```

**If The Table Isn't Currently Receiving Writes**

```sql
ALTER TABLE pokemon DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS league_max;
ALTER TABLE pokemon ADD CONSTRAINT league_max ...
```

This is a simple approach that works on CockroachDB and Postgres for any kind of constraint, but isn't safe to use in production on a live table and can be expensive if the table is large.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE pokemon 
  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS league_max,
  ADD CONSTRAINT league_max ...
```